# iOS 8 update broke my splash screen

Tags: ios, ipad, splash-screen

Its a strange error. Not really sure what I need to change. I have had this working for ages until we updated iPad to iOS 8. The splash page loads ok but then squashes down and has a black bar next to it. Have added images to show what I am talking about. I know this is not a programming question but spent the last 6 hours trying to solve this.

[image: Splash Screen]

[image]

Anyone else run into similar issues out there? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would just re-create the splash image. And pay attention to whatever process you're using to rotate it... some image editors will "rotate" an image by just changing the metadata, instead of properly re-aranging all the bits in the file to the new orientation.

Comment: its weird that it loads ok then squashes down to image 2

Comment: It has nothing to do with the image size or rotation. It loads fine (Image 1) but after 2-3 sec it changes to the second image. Its the same image.